# Custom class containing a scalar categorical displays as "[1x1 categorical]" instead of displaying the category

Tags: matlab, class, oop, struct, categories

On MATLAB R2014b, when you have a `struct` (or custom class) having a field that is a scalar `categorical`, when displaying the `struct` it will show `[1x1 categorical]` instead of what I want to achieve as shown below.

[MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example):

```
struct.field = categorical({'category'})
```

Output:

```
struct = 
    field: [1x1 categorical]
```

My desired output:

```
struct = 
    field: category
```

or:

```
struct = 
    field: category    [1x1 categorical]
```

I want this, because I'm writing some classes that have a `categorical` property that is always scalar; because I know this by definition, I don't need the objects' category to be displayed as `[1x1 categorical]`. When displaying the custom objects, I'd like it to show the category instead.

I could overload `disp` in my class methods, but then I'd need to rewrite a lot of displaying code from `disp` itself instead of merely changing the way a scalar `categorical` in a `struct` field shows.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? If your answer involves overloading `disp` in the class definition, then I want to see how you could display the object's other properties like a normal `disp(obj)` would, in addition to displaying the `categorical` property the way I want. Any ideas or thoughts you have might help me write my own answer, so please share any.

Comment: Even if you override `disp` in the class this behavior wouldn't change. You would need to write a custom `disp` method for the struct itself that would check for a scalar and display that appropriately.

Comment: @Suever - Exactly, that is quite a lot of work, I presume. I was wonder if another way exists that I haven't thought of. My first idea was to actually rewrite `disp` by first displaying the category, then use the normal `disp` function for displaying everything but the category field. How do I call the non-overloaded `disp` function? If I use `disp` in my redefinition in the class methods, I recursively call that very class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but today I needed this again. I thought of another way to display scalar `categorical` variables. The following example class does the trick.

```
classdef dispfmtTest < matlab.mixin.Copyable
    properties
        prop = categorical(1) % default value is a scalar categorical
    end
    methods
        function dispfmt(obj) % dispfmtTest object to display format
            obj.prop = char(obj.prop); % convert to char type
        end
        function disp(self)
            obj = copy(self); % copy is provided by superclass
            dispfmt(obj)
            disp@matlab.mixin.Copyable(obj) % call superclass disp
            delete(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

The `dispfmtTest` class is a subclass of `matlab.mixin.Copyable`, which is in turn a subclass of `handle`. It provides the `copy` method to the `disfmtTest` class, which is used to temporarily create a copy of which the value of property `prop` is changed to whatever desired display format in method `dispfmt`. Then, the modified copy of the object is displayed using the regular `disp` function as provided by `matlab.mixin.Copyable`.

*Demo*

Running `obj = dispfmtTest` yields

```
d = 
  dispfmtTest with properties:

    prop: '1'
```

and `class(d.prop)` yields

```
ans =
categorical
```

This is the behaviour as I expected. Support for array properties can be achieved too using `isscalar`.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this for a while, I think I finally have something that works for displaying these scalar `categorical` values within a custom class.

The basic idea is that I overload the `get` method for the property that is holding the `categorical`. I can then check the call stack to see *what* is trying to get the value of the variable. If it's our overloaded `disp` method (which is called any time we want to display our class), then I return the category name if it's only a scalar `categorical`. Otherwise, I return the value of the property itself (as a `categorical`).

It's definitely not the most elegant due to it's reliance on `dbstack` but it seems to work quite well.

```
classdef categoryclass < handle

    properties
        a = categorical({'category'});
    end

    methods
        % Get Method for "a" property
        function res = get.a(self)

            % Get the call stack to determine *what* called this
            stack = dbstack();

            methodname = sprintf('%s.disp', class(self));

            % If it is a scalar and it was called by our overloaded display
            % method, then return the category name
            if isscalar(self.a) && isa(self.a, 'categorical') && ...
                strcmp(methodname, stack(end).name)
                res = categories(self.a);
                res = res{1};
            % Otherwise return just the value itself
            else
                res = self.a;
            end
        end

        % This ensure that disp() shows up in the stack
        function disp(self)
            % Simply call the built-in display function
            builtin('disp', self);
        end
    end
end
```

Now if we try this out.

```
cls = categoryclass()

  categoryclass with properties:

       a: 'category'
```

Check that when we request the value we *actually* get a `categorical`.

```
class(cls.a)

    ans =  

       categorical
```

Now change the value of it.

```
cls.a = categorical({'another category'})

  categoryclass with properties:

       a: 'another category'
```

Now use two categories

```
cls.a = categorical({'one', 'two'})

  categoryclass with properties:

       a: [1x2 categorical]
```

> **NOTE:** This only appears to be an issue in R2014b and R2015a. It was fixed in all later releases.

Comment: Very nice that you found somewhere (where?) this only applies to those two releases. I'm looking into this further tonight or tomorrow. Take a look at http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/displaying-objects-in-the-command-window.html and http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/type-sect1-title-here.html (notice the funny .html page name someone apparently forgot to edit). Note that not using a semicolon `;` will call the `display` function, which will in turn call the `disp` function, so overloading both `display` and `disp` might do the trick.

Comment: @Erik found through experimentation. I'm looking into this in more detail. Will post shortly!

Comment: @Erik I have updated it with a class definition that should work as you describe.